# Join multiple cropped images to form a single image in iOS

Tags: iphone, uikit

I have cropped multiple images from a bigger image, now I have to join these cropped images to form a new image which can be loaded into a single imageview.

Comment: Go right ahead and join them. Did you have a question?

Comment: i have cropped images and loaded them to imageviews, now i need to combine or join these image views and form 1 single image, and i am stuck here

Comment: Why do you want to create a single image? Why can't you just add your many imageviews as subviews of your single imageview and lay them out using their frame property. I'm new to this, so I may have the wrong end of the stick.

Comment: I need to create 1 image because i need to resize the image so as to be seen on the screen.There may be 1 image or 26 images or may be more and all have to be seen on the same screen. so they need to be resized, accordingly.Pls help me out

Comment: I believe you can resize using an imageview. I believe you can control how the subviews are resized by setting autoresizing and contentmode properties.

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do is create an image context, draw your images into this context, then convert this context to an image.

```
//create context
CGSize endImageSize = CGSizeMake(128.0, 128.0);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(endImageSize);

// draw images into this context
[anImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,64, 64)];
[anotherImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(64, 64, 64, 64)];

//convert context into a UIImage
UIImage *endImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

//cleanup
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

That being said, it is probably better to just make a UIImageView for each image.